# how can i get lsh value from opencv sift descriptor

Tags: python, opencv

i want to get lsh hashing value from opencv sift descriptor

first , i get sift descriptor like below

```
def getSiftDescriptor(imagepath):
    img  = cv2.imread(imagepath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(img,None)
    return des.reshape(1,-1)
```

second , i use NearPy package(https://github.com/pixelogik/NearPy) to calculate lsh value like below

```
rbp = RandomBinaryProjections('default', 100)
def getLsh(descriptor):
    rbp.reset(len(descriptor.reshape(1,-1)[0]))
    return rbp.hash_vector(descriptor.reshape(1,-1)[0])
```

finally, i call function like below

```
getLsh(getSiftDescriptor('image path'))
```

i expect get same lsh hashing value from same image ,

but this function return different value whenever i called.

please, recommend python package to get lsh hashing value like this situation or some way get lsh hashing value from opencv sift descriptor

thank you for your help

Comment: 1. How is the value different from what you expect (give examples, perhaps your understanding of Locality Sensitive Hashing is wrong?) 2.  Your code example is incomplete: `getLsh` is not defined. 3. You mention the `lshash` module requires fixed length input. If you're asking if there's a module that allows variable length inputs, then you're asking here for others to recommend a library, which tends to attract opinionated answers. Such a question is off-topic for StackOverflow. Try to find a solution to that subproblem and report difficulties with your approach.

Comment: thanks your comment, Oliver W. i edit my question